# Update Primefaces datatable Rows

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I want to know how to update a PrimeFaces Datatable rows. This is my datatable photo to understand me well:

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1jGz.png

I want to choose for each row his respective state and then click Save States button to save these values.

This is my xhtml page code:

```
<p:panel header="List Of Players For: #gameMB.selectedGame.teamCompetitionByGuestTeam}">
  <p:dataTable var="gam" value="#{gamePlayerMB.listGamePlayerGuest}">
    <p:column headerText="Name Lastname">
        <h:outputText value="#{gam.playerName}/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>                                      
     <p:selectOneRadio value="#{gam.state}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Titulaire" itemValue="Titulaire" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Remplaçant" itemValue="Remplaçant" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Blesse" itemValue="Blesse" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Non retenu" itemValue="Non retenu" />
     </p:selectOneRadio>
    </p:column>
 </p:dataTable>
 <f:facet name="footer">
<p:commandButton value="Save States"
    action="#{gamePlayerMB.testRadioGuest}" />
</f:facet>
</p:panel>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should have used simple `h:outputText` as a component to render
   the Player's state (Titulare,Blessé,...)
2. Use **primefaces datatable** `editable="true"` with `p:selectOneMenu` in the `p:cellEditor` to render the list of available choices.
3. here's a [head start](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowEditing.jsf) link.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you right, You just want to create table with edit function. For solving this trouble just pass your table and your button to form.

```
<h:form>
   <p:dataTable var="gam" value="#{gamePlayerMB.listGamePlayerGuest}">
      ...
   </p:dataTable>
   <p:commandButton value="Save States" action="#{gamePlayerMB.testRadioGuest}" />
</h:form>
```

In this case on Save-button click all form will be sent to the server (with all your changing). Your testRadioGuest method may looked like this

```
private void testRadioGuest(){
   for(Player player: listGamePlayerGuest){
      System.out.println(player);
   }
}
```

All state changing must be saved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem is the method saveStates, what i should write on it

Comment: You may write there nothing. If you've defined getter and setter for your List and put all to form, it will be updated automatically.

Comment: Sorry, I had given wrong name for method in my answer, it confused you :)

Comment: I think i forget to mention that these values should be saved into database. These rows are list of Objects, each object has a string attribute named "State" which save state for each player

Comment: Yes, all your objects in your list will be updated. Just add interaction with your db. If you want update only rows which was changed, you must store also copy of your list (or list of their hashes). Then on save you must find changed rows, update them into db and make new copy.

Comment: i tried to do like you said (i mean to update the hole list) and this is my update method: 
`private void testRadioGuest(){

   for(Player player: listGamePlayerGuest){

     getGamePlayerService().updateGamePlayer(player);

   }

}`
But nothing happens

Comment: what i cannot understand, how state values will be transmitted ? this is the problem